# Sending data into Datastore from Android App

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I already read some question here about sending data from android app to datastore but there too old i think there are changes searching through the web doesn't help. I have an Android app specifically a `Form` composed of string, integers and image. I wanted to store it in datastore and retrieve later in both my `Webserver using PHP` and in my `Android App`. Anybody knows how to accomplish this, till now im still confused about storing data in datastore. There are so many involve like `endpoints`. Any guidlines, snippets or such any resources.

Comment: You are right! the tutorials out there are outdated. I had to manage a lot other things to make those codes work. It will be great if somebody can point to a new reliable code/Tutorial.

Comment: @SrujanBarai, Sir Did you find anything usefull about sending data into datastore using android?

Comment: Don't call me sir. Yes I succeeded in sending data from android app to my php server and saving it to my database. Are you asking that?

Comment: @SrujanBarai, Yes. until now i can't figure it out how to do that. Did you use DATASTORE?

Comment: nup, mysql database.

Comment: @SrujanBarai, same with me. I'm still looking with someone who can provide `Tutorials` using datastore.